# Javascript passed string with \r in the string is being interpreted to newline

Tags: javascript, string, split, substr, stripping

I am receiving a new string like so "ABCD\richard"

I want to be able to strip off "ABCD\" off of the string. However JavaScript is interpreting the  "\r" as a new line metacharacters. I imagine I will have the same issues with any metacharacters. I am looking for a way to strip the string of "ABCD\" on all strings passed.

The end result should be "richard" as the final string. This is what I have tried so far:

string.substr(5,100);
string.split('ABCD\');

Here is my code:

```
function export_sal(user)
{
    var noABCD = user.replace(/ABCD\\/, '');
    console.log(noABCD);
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;">
    <div onclick="export_sal('<?php echo $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];?>');" class='btn btn-info btn-md' id="e_sal">SAL Export
```

the result of the console output is like this:

ABCD
ichard

I need the console.log output to show: richard

I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: How are you receiving this string? If you're declaring it in your code you can simply escape your backslashes eg `var string = "ABCD\\richard"`

Comment: I am actually receiving it on page load from php. submit_sal('<?php echo $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];?>');

Comment: In that case, you'll only need to escape your backslashes in the replace call as in fauxserious' answer.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and post a [mcve]. It looks like there may be some miscommunication occurring here.

Comment: Please add the entire snippet to your question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: Your snippet works as posted when called with `"ABCD\\richard"`. Please post an actual MCVE (the V is for Verifiable) showing the entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape not only `\` but `\n`, `\r`, `\t` for this to work correctly.

```
"ABCD\richard".replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\t", "\\t").split(/\\/)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4c5b5v2k/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to escape the `\` character so it's not read as a special character.

```
var noABCD = str.replace(/ABCD\\/, '');
```

https://regex101.com/r/UjGI4o/1

Comment: I have tried the above and on the console.log result I am receiving the following: "ABCD\richard"